# navigate to other screen remove back button from app bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have Four screen like 1,2,3 and 4 when i navigate from screen 4 to screen 1 using bellow code. the back arrow button in my appbar of screen 1 it's automatically removed don't know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          '/screen4', ModalRoute.withName('/screen1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this below code in the screen 1 app-bar

`AppBar(
      title: Text("Title"),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      ),
    );`